# How to reflow a text paragraph in the CLion editor?

Tags: clion

How does one reflow a text paragraph when using the CLion editor?  In GNU Emacs, this is done using M-q. For some reason, stack overflow will not allow me to post that question adding this additional text.

Answer (score 0):

In the Menu bar: "Edit | Fill Paragraph".

See also in Preferences: "Editor | Code Style | Right margin (columns)", which will affect Fill Paragraph.

Comment: `Fill Paragraph` is always grayed out for me in CLion 2018.2. In PyCharm 2018.2 it seems to work on Python docstrings, but on JavaScript JSDoc comments it's ignorant of the `*` left column.